# SBS 2008: Cannot ping clients over VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-sbs-2008

Today I upgraded our host server to XenServer 6.0 and upgraded the SBS 2008 VM with the latest XenTools. Everything has gone fine.

When I connect to the SBS server over VPN, it connects fine. From my local PC over the VPN, I can ping SBS but cannot ping any other PC on the same network as SBS. If I RDP in to the SBS server, I can ping anything on the network.

Does anyone know what else I can try? Really stuck on this one myself. :(

EDIT: When XenServer was upgraded, the virtual network adapter in SBS was replaced and given a new IP, so I've had to setup the SBS local IP settings again. Prior to the upgrade the VPN worked fine. This problem has been occurring since the upgrade only. I've tried removing and reinstalling Routing and Remote Access, followed by a reboot, but it's still not working.

Comment: What VPN solution are you using?

Comment: I'm using the VPN that comes with SBS 2008.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the VPN server capability of SBS then it sounds like you need to configure it for LAN routing. Unless you configure it for LAN routing you'll only have access to the VPN server from the VPN client but nothing on the LAN beyond the VPN server (like other hosts on the LAN).

Comment: Please see the edit in the original post. Also I've checked and IPv4 uses LAN and dial on demand routing (default option) under Routing and Remote Access properties. Still not working though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem. I even tried to use a VPN server on a Linux Virtual Machine inside XenServer, authenticating on LDAP with FreeRADIUS and everything, just to find out the problem is really the XenServer 6.0.

Take a look at this forum post on the Citrix boards, there is a alternative - it seems that removing the XenTools solves the problem. An alternative is using NAT on the VPN server:

http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=305183

Good luck